# Hazelcast predicate could not find child class attribute

Tags: inheritance, predicate, hazelcast

I have a parent and child class and I am storing each class' instances in two seperate homogeneous IMap instances.

here is also a CacheManager class which is responsible about cache operations and management. So the methods of this class are using parent class instances as abstraction.

When I try to get items with SqlPredicate , it simply does not recognize the child class attributes in cache. When I inspect cache items, all the items are right but when predicate queries them, instance recognizes them as parent class instances so it can not find the attributes on child classes. It starts with "there is no element as ".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: afaik, when querying, hazelcast is resolving the attribute for each entry (ie Extractable interface). it use the actual class stored in the map. so, using an abstract class should not impact the query. can you post an example of your code and an exception ?

Comment: @JérémieB it is pretty basic actually. one wrapper class has this parent class attribute in it but the instance is a child class one and when I try to query the items with SqlPredicate based on the child attributes, it says  "There is no suitable accessor for 'childAttribute' on class 'class com.thu.a.model.cache.ChildCacheItem'"

Comment: And the query is: childCacheItem.childAttribute1 in (4) and childCacheItem.childAttribute2 in (7). When I replace the attributes with parent attributes it works by the way

Answer (score 0):

Can you please open a github issue if you're sure it is a bug and add your source to it so that we're able to reproduce and fix the issue?

It sounds to me as it should work the way you expect but maybe there's something simple to be fixed on either side.